# Python PIP Installing Issues

Tags: python, caching, installation, typeerror, traceback

Having great difficulty installing the following:
argparse==1.2.1, beautifulsoup4==4.3.2 & wsgiref==0.1.2. I receive the same error each when attempting to install any of them:

```
C:\>pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 339, in r
un
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 385, in prepar
e_files
      req_to_install.run_egg_info()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 310, in ru
n_egg_info
      self.setup_py, self.name,
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 281, in se
tup_py
      import setuptools  # noqa
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 11, in <mo
dule>
      from setuptools.extension import Extension
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 8, in <mo
dule>
      from .dist import _get_unpatched
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module
>
      from setuptools.depends import Require
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\depends.py", line 6, in <modu
le>
      from setuptools import compat
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 19, in <modu
le>
      from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
      class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 214, in SimpleHTTPRequestHa
ndler
      mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
    File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 351, in init
      db.read_windows_registry()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 254, in read_windows_registry
      with _winreg.OpenKey(hkcr, subkeyname) as subkey:
  TypeError: must be string without null bytes or None, not str

Collecting argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 339, in r
un
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 385, in prepar
e_files
      req_to_install.run_egg_info()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 310, in ru
n_egg_info
      self.setup_py, self.name,
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 281, in se
tup_py
      import setuptools  # noqa
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 11, in <mo
dule>
      from setuptools.extension import Extension
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 8, in <mo
dule>
      from .dist import _get_unpatched
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module
>
      from setuptools.depends import Require
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\depends.py", line 6, in <modu
le>
      from setuptools import compat
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 19, in <modu
le>
      from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
      class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 214, in SimpleHTTPRequestHa
ndler
      mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
    File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 351, in init
      db.read_windows_registry()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 254, in read_windows_registry
      with _winreg.OpenKey(hkcr, subkeyname) as subkey:
  TypeError: must be string without null bytes or None, not str
```

What can I do to get these things installed or get this cache wiped? I was able to install other packages just fine.

Comment: have you upgraded pip and setup tools to the last versions?

Comment: @hexerei-software pip install --upgrade pip? It says it's already up-to-date. Edit: Forgot to mention setuptools is also up-to-date.

Comment: all i can tell, is that he gets a null string when he is trying to get the system mime types from the windows registry... maybe a rights problem? running as Administrator? no key in your registry? somewhere around there the bad stuff is happening :)

Comment: How might one resolve this barring a wipe?

Comment: I would love to help, but i only use windows in a vm and only seldomly. Happy in Mac and Unix worlds since ages :)